# Get Checked Checkbox values

Tags: jquery

I have table with check boxes in it.and the CSS for the check box is GridCheckBox, I want to read the check boxes tool tip into an array with , separated.

I am using this function. But this not getting the checked items. but getting the unchecked items correctly.

This works well

```
var titles = [];
$('#ListGrid .GridCheckBox').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('title')) {
        titles.push($(this).attr('title'));
    }
});
```

And this not working(Checked items)

```
var titles = [];
$('#ListGrid .GridCheckBox:checked').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('title')) {
        titles.push($(this).attr('title'));
    }
});
```

Comment: what version of jQuery, and please show your HTML markup.

Comment: Post the HTML you are using, or if it is long make a jsFiddle please

Comment: assuming the double quotes at the beginning of the selector are a typo in the question and not in your original code, this should work fine.

Comment: @Chad Please find the markup in http://sharetext.org/ACG9

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet  no its copy paste mistake... this the orginal           var titles = [];
                $('#ListGrid .GridCheckBox:checked').each(function() {
                    if ($(this).attr('title')) {
                        titles.push($(this).attr('title'));
                    }
                });

Comment: I set you up a jsFiddle for us to use [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kqsbt/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of cos it doesn't work. The class ".GridCheckBox" u applied on is on the parent "span" and not the "checkbox input" itself!

you can do this though:

```
$('#ListGrid .GridCheckBox').each(function() {
var target = $(this);
if (target.find("input:checkbox").is(":checked")) {
    titles.push(target.attr('title'));
}});
```

assuming one span.GridCheckBox contains only one checkbox input.

Comment: yes it worked. thanks 'code'  var titles = [];
                $('#ListGrid .GridCheckBox').each(function() {
                    var target = $(this);
                    if (target.find("input:checkbox").is(":checked")) {
                        titles.push($(this).attr('title'));
                    }
                }); 

               //     alert(titles.toString());
                if (titles.length > 0) {
                 $("#SelectedEmployeeIds").val(titles.join(','));
                }
                 'code'

Answer (score 1):

Well another way to do it is to use jQuery $.map() in this example i grab all selectboxes by name. For example:

```
var titles = $.map($("input[name='name_of_checkboxes']:checked"),function(a){return a.title;});
```

Shuld return a array with selected - selectbox titles.

**EDIT**

To get none selected selectboxes you culd use this

```
  var not_selected = $.map($("input[name='name_of_checkboxes']:not(:checked)"),function(a){return a.title;});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="name_of_checkboxes" checked="checked" title="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="name_of_checkboxes" title="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="name_of_checkboxes" checked="checked" title="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="name_of_checkboxes" title="4"/>
```

Over n out

Answer (score 0):

To try to eliminate any mistakes, and also to aid performance, try this instead:

```
$('#ListGrid .GridCheckBox').filter(':checked').each( ..
```

Because `:checked` [is a jQuery extension](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) it doesn't perform as well as the native browser methods for matching objects.

Comment: this doesn't work  $('#ListGrid .GridCheckBox').filter(':checked').each(function() {
                    if ($(this).attr('title')) {
                        titles.push($(this).attr('title'));
                    }
                });
                alert(titles.toString());                                                 ouput empty